# How to work with guest Circuit users from smartphone apps?

Tags: circuit-sdk

I want to use circuit as a videocall system in a B2C environment in which only the backend call agents are Circuit users (but the end-clients are not!!).
The only way I see to establish a videocall would be by creating a new conversation, get the url guest link and send it to the end-client.
This could be a “not-that-bad” possibility in a PC web portal front end….but in the case of a smartphone app (ie Ionic-Cordova) that link would redirect the end client to the Circuit app download site, forcing the user to install Circuit app which would not be accepted in the general case.
Is there any other possibility to implement a use case like this from Smartphone apps by embedding the guest connectivity in the app making Circuit transparent for the end client? Any possibility by using a pool of dummy Circuit users to be assigned temporarily to the app users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good question. There are two problems as pointed out by you.

**1. SDK cannot be used without an authenticated Circuit user**

I.e. the SDK has no support for guest access other than retrieving the guest access link. Workarounds are:

a) use the guest link and have the non-Circuit users join using their Circuit web or mobile client, or

b) create a new conversation each time and use a pool of users. But this workaround does not look intuitive and have actually never tried it in an app.

**2. Guest users require Circuit app**

Again as pointed out correctly, if going with a) above, the mobile client users would need the Circuit app to join a guest session.

**Conclusion**
For desktop users 1a is probably the best option. But for mobile users you'd have to try a workaround with a pool of users.

We are aware of these limitation and are looking into a better solution to address your use case. I will update this post once we have more information of the details and timeframe.